# how to play audio files with crossfading on Linux?

Tags: linux, music, mplayer

Is it possible to play audio files with a crossfading effect (track *i* fades out, track *i+1* fades in) on Linux? A special case is when a single track is repeated in an endless loop.

I'm using `mplayer`, but might consider other applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about mplayer, but Rhythmbox has an option to crossfade between tracks. To activate it go to Edit > Settings > Playback and check the *Crossfading backend* option.

There's also the *Auto-DJ* feature of [mixxx](https://www.mixxx.org/) that does that but it may be a little bit overkill for your intended purposes.